# Strangely closing diff sections in git conflict

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

After performing `git pull --rebase origin master` from my branch I got a conflict in some file that looks like this:

```
<<<<<<< 640da0acfa7e7bff40009acf1e5b0eccfae97637                                                                                                                                                          
        def some_func(some_arg):
            some_code                                                                                                                                             

=======                                                                                                                                                                                                   
<<<<<<< ca49b7324540347ba8823072feaa1bd23a5be97d                                                                                                                                                          
>>>>>>> name_of_my_last_commit_on_that_branch
```

These sections don't seem to close properly. There are no more `<<<<<<`, `======` or `>>>>>>` in this file. How should I think about it? Is it a bug or some feature that I am not aware of?

I am using git 2.21.0.

EDIT: I am sure that on branches' HEADs there are no left conflict markers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you had a conflict marker committed in a previous commit. You might see it  if you run `git log -p`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by using `git rebase -i` to squash my previous commits that contained left merge markers with commits that removed them.

I didn't realize that `pull --rebase` applies all ahead commits one by one, so if I had markers left and fixed somewhere in the past I still had to deal with them anyway.

Comment: Yes, pull rebase, does, in a nutshell, a `git fetch` and `git rebase` (which itself applies commits one by one, by definition).